# sending multiple messages with different length to the same rank

Tags: mpi, openmpi

Let's say I have 3 ranks.

Rank 0 receives 1 `MPI_INT` from rank 1 and receives 10 `MPI_INT` from rank 2:

```
MPI_Recv(buf1, 1, MPI_INT,
    1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
MPI_Recv(buf2, 10, MPI_INT,
    2, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Rank 1 and rank 2 sends 1 and 10 `MPI_INT` to rank 0, respectively. The MPI_Recv is a blocking call. Let's say the 10 `MPI_INIT` from rank 2 arrives before the 1 `MPI_INT` from rank 1. At this point, rank 0 blocks there waiting for data from rank 1.

In this case, could the first `MPI_Recv` return? Data from rank 2 arrives first, but the data couldn't fit into buf1 which could contain one integer.

And then the message from rank 1 arrives. Is MPI able to pick this message and let the first `MPI_Recv` return?

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify a source when calling `MPI_Recv()`, you do not have time worry about the order of the messages. The first `MPI_Recv()` will return when 1 `MPI_INT` is received from rank `1`, and the second `MPI_Recv()` will return when 10 `MPI_INT` are received from rank `2`.

If you had `MPI_Recv(..., source=MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ...)` it would have been a different story.

Feel free to write a simple program with some `sleep()` here and there if you still need to convince yourself.